# What is the logic behind elastic query with should and multi_match?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

What I want to do is to get all the documents that contain *query 1*, *query 2*, **or** *query 3* in *message* or *path* fields as a result. I tried to make a query in many ways, starting with this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "*query 1*",
            "fields": [
              "message",
              "path"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "*query 2*",
            "fields": [
              "message",
              "path"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "*query 3*",
            "fields": [
              "message",
              "path"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

However it returns only documents that containt *query 1* or *query 2* in *message* or *path* fields. It skips the last one - *query 3*. When I change my query to that form:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "*query 1*",
            "fields": [
              "message",
              "path"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "*query 2*",
            "fields": [
              "message",
              "path"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "*query 3*",
            "fields": [
              "message",
              "path"
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 2
    }
  }
}
```

I get the results with *path* or *message* fields containing **only** *query 3*.
What is logic behind that (bool + should + multi_match) and is there any possibility to make a query to get all the documents containing all 3 queries inside *message* or *path* fields?

Sample index data:

```
facility:
    workflow
line:
logger:
host:
@timestamp:
message:
    Updating assignment bg938475-8604-4bh6-vf90-ad4vg462g6y7 
server:
timestamp:
source_host:
@version:
    1
className:
userName:
sessionId:
level:
method:
_id:
_type:
    _doc
_index:
    service-
_score:
    -
```

and second one:

```
http_version:
    1.0
status:
    200
tags:
host:
@timestamp:
    Jun 10, 2021 @ 12:34:14.000
useragent.build:
useragent.major:
useragent.name:
useragent.os:
useragent.minor:
useragent.patch:
useragent.os_name:
useragent.device:
server_name:
visitor_ip:
body_bytes_sent:
referrer:
session_id:
@version:
path:
    /api/assignment/assignment/kop90vh6-c2s5-4042-80ol-b6gh2b9846a3/commit
request_time:
remote_user:
type:
    nginx_access
method:
    POST
_id:
_type:
    _doc
_index:
    nginx-access-
_score:
    -
```

In above example - *query 1*, *query 2* and *query 3* are different UUIDs.

Comment: that's weird. Can you please share some sample index data on which you are performing your query?

Comment: Question has been extended with sample data.

Comment: can you please just share only the sample UUID's which you are querying ?

Comment: Sure, as show above, they look like this: bg938475-8604-4bh6-vf90-ad4vg462g6y7, kop90vh6-c2s5-4042-80ol-b6gh2b9846a3. So the "query" looks like this: "query": "\*kop90vh6-c2s5-4042-80ol-b6gh2b9846a3*"